# English word for a "pavé" in French

Tags: terminology

In French, a subset $P \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ that can be written as the product of $n$ finite open intervals is called a "pavé".

Is there a word in English to designate such an object?

Comment: I have seen them called *open hyperrectangles*.

Comment: @WillJagy Does "pavement", "paved thing" or "paving slab" really help the English reader of mathematics in this context?

Comment: @WillJagy then I'd go all the way and use "paver." Or maybe "sett"!  We could have a set of setts.  :-)

Comment: @PatrickStevens I suppose i don't really know. It helps me when I find a familiar root for a word, so I automatically made a comment.

Comment: @quid good catch. I know I have seen sett in crossword puzzles, but It is not even in my (early) edition of the OED. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sett_%28paving%29

Comment: @WillJagy to be honest I did not know the word before. What I did know is that while the French word is also used for the pavement, it  means the individual stone too and this is the association intended there. So I looked up what that'd be in English.

Comment: @quid this is a link from the wiki page, very nice and more than I knew: http://www.pavingexpert.com/setts01.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, the term "$k$-cell" is used for the product of $k$ closed intervals.  This appears to be standard enough in English mathematics that it is the title of the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-cell_(mathematics)).

Comment: Following your link I also found https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/k-cell.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, I just noticed you asked about the product of *open* instead of closed intervals.  Personally, I'd use the term "open $k$-cell" in such a scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Since a "box" or "brick" is a product of $n$ finite *closed* intervals, you should be able to use "open box". I would make sure to define it the first time you use it, though, since "open box" is a phrase in colloquial English already.